# MySQL LEFT JOIN error 1064 when querying Wordpress database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to retrieve some data from a Wordpress database:

```
SELECT M.meta_value,wp_users.ID
FROM wp_postmeta AS M 
WHERE meta_key = "_from_email" AND post_id = 277124
LEFT JOIN wp_users ON M.meta_value = wp_users.user_email
```

Here, my intention is to get the `ID` of the `wp_users` user who has an `email` identical to one in `meta_value`.

But I get the following error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN wp_users ON M.meta_value = wp_users.user_email

Do you see any syntax error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

left join must be declare before where clause

```
SELECT M.meta_value,wp_users.ID
FROM wp_postmeta AS M 
LEFT JOIN wp_users ON M.meta_value = wp_users.user_email
WHERE meta_key = "_from_email" AND post_id = 277124
```

*be sure you are not using column for left joined  table in where clause otherwise this implies that the join work as an inner join .. eventually move these column in the related  ON clause*

Comment: Thanks, I was going crazy, I'll take your advice into account